# Are "vague" edit comments acceptable?

Tags: discussion, editing

Often, I edit questions, and put a simple comment into the edit box, like "minor edit" or "major changes" and what not. Is this too vague and needs to be more specific, or is it fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More specificity doesn't hurt, but it's also not really necessary. It's usually pretty easy to see from the diff provided what the changes are. Really, the edit summary is most helpful for large edits to give a reviewer an overview of the purpose of the changes, to reduce the amount of processing necessary to understand what they are looking at when they scroll through the changes.

Comment: I occasionally use edit comments to make gentle hints to the post author, eg "Added attribution for material quoted from Wikipedia". ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, they can be helpful for that as well